# Is there a way to launch a GUI program without a window on Wayland?

Tags: xorg, display, window, wayland, 23.10

I just recently switched from X11 to Wayland and was wondering if there was any way to launch a GUI program without it actually occupying a window on the screen. I used to accomplish this in X using Xvfb like so `Xvfb :99 & DISPLAY=:99 some_app_with_gui &`, which would launch the program in a virtual display that couldn't physically be seen on any monitor, but that doesn't appear to be working in Wayland, as the window still shows up on screen.

Anyone have any ideas?